# Why am I getting an error calling for an object reference in C# API Call

Tags: c#, api

I have an app that has a lot of C# API calls and I have one call that is saying "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property". The code that is giving that error looks like this:

```
    [HttpGet("api/foo/bar/data/{dataId}")]
    public List<Model> GetDataSource(string dataId)
    {
      return ModelBuilder.GetDataSource(dataId);
    }
```

I have other API's in this file that are the exact same structure but they are fine. The only difference is that the others are calling a different builder file. I have included the references to the new builder file in my using statements and the opening statements of the class.

One of the other API's that is working is:

```
    [HttpGet("api/foo/bar/model/{modelid}")]
    public List<Model> GetModel(string modelid)
    {
      return mBuilder.GetModel(modelid);
    }
```

Further, if I change the builder file that it's going to it resolves the error. The definition of the method in the builder file is the exact same regardless of which file I put it in as I just copied what I had written and pasted it into the other file.

** Edit to show what the Builder files look like***

So my Builder files are both defined with public class and from my perspective seem like they are identical files.

The ModelBuilder looks like:

```
//using statements
  namespace Business
  {
    public class ModelBuilder
    {
      public List<Model> GetDataSource(string dataId)
    {
      var object = this.entityCollection.Find(item => item.id == dataId).ToList();
      var entityIDs = new HashSet<string>();

      foreach (var object in objects)
      {
        entityIDs.Add(object.id);
      }

      if (object == null)
      {
        return new List<Model>();
      }

      var filter = Builders<AllowedObjects>.Filter.In("id", entityIDs);
      var items = allowedObjectsCollection.Find(filter).ToList();
      var objects = new List<Model>();

      foreach (var mObj in items)
      {
        var obj = tmBuilder.ConvertFromAllowedObjectToModel(mObj);
        obj.Add(obj);
      }

      return obj;
    }
    }
  }
```

My mBuilder file looks like:

```
//using statements
  namespace Utilities
  {
    public class mBuilder
    {
      public List<Model> GetDataSource(string dataId)
    {
      var object = this.entityCollection.Find(item => item.id == dataId).ToList();
      var entityIDs = new HashSet<string>();

      foreach (var object in objects)
      {
        entityIDs.Add(object.id);
      }

      if (object == null)
      {
        return new List<Model>();
      }

      var filter = Builders<AllowedObjects>.Filter.In("id", entityIDs);
      var items = allowedObjectsCollection.Find(filter).ToList();
      var objects = new List<Model>();

      foreach (var mObj in items)
      {
        var obj = tmBuilder.ConvertFromAllowedObjectToModel(mObj);
        obj.Add(obj);
      }

      return obj;
    }
    }
```

So I'm confused at why I get the object reference error when I try to send the API to the ModelBuilder but not when I send it to the mBuilder.

Comment: Check `GetDataSource` is declared as a `static` method.

Comment: Can you also show us the ones that are fine?

Comment: Check that ModelBuilder is an instance of that type, instead of the type itself in the GetDataSource method.
In the GetModel method, you're probably refering to an instance, with a variable called mBuilder, instead of ModelBuilder.

Comment: It looks like `ModelBuilder` is a class and `mBuilder` an instance. Charles' comment above holds.

Comment: @Enigmativity, so I'm still kind of new to C# development, how do I know that one is an instance because both files start with public class ...?

Comment: @kemosabe - You need to show us what you mean?

Comment: @kemosabe - That code is fake. You can't define a variable called `object` and you certainly can't define it twice. You need to post your real code.

Comment: @KenWhite - It doesn't look that way from the code that's been posted.

Comment: @kemosabe A `class` is a template for objects. An object is an instance of a class. `public class MyClass {...}` defines a class. `var x = new MyClass()` creates an instance (`x` is the instance of type `MyClass`). Your code is failing because you're trying to reference a property on a class. You can't do that unless the property is `static` and yours is not. Therefore, you need an instance (a variable of type `ModelBuilder`, like `mBuilder`).

Comment: @KenWhite - I said so before the OP posted the code. The assumption was then proven untrue.

Comment: @VicF - Not according to the code that the OP has posted.